# How can I select only the first record with each foreign key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

I have rows in a contact details database that look like this:

```
contactID - bioID - AddressLine1 - City 
393         1       1 nowhere st   toronto
3921        1       2 somewhere st vancouver
3231        2       1 anywhere rd  barrie
1122        2       2 overthere st halifax
```

I am currently inner joining this to a bio table with columns `firstname, lastname` etc and the results look like this:

```
bioid    firstname    lastname    addressline1    city
1        some         guy         1 nowhere st    toronto
1        some         guy         2 somewhere st  vancouver
2        that         girl        1 anywhere rd   barrie
2        that         girl        2 overthere st  halifax
```

So I am basically getting 2 rows for every bio. Is there anyway I can select this all as one row like this:

```
bioid    firstname    lastname   addressline1x1   cityx1    addressline1x2    cityx2
1        some         guy        1 nowhere st     toronto   2 somewhere st    vancouver
2        that         girl       1 anywhere rd    barrie    2 overthere st    halifax
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

EDIT:

Thanks a lot to Denis and Justin I was able to solve this problem. However, now I have another.

I would like to actually select the addresses as 1 field such as:

```
bioid    firstname    lastname    primary address         secondary address
1        some         guy         1 nowhere st, toronto   2 somewhere st, vanvouver
2        that         girl        1 anywhere rd, barrie   2 overthere st, halifax
```

I know I can do it by concatenating columns like:

```
cd1.addressline1 + ', ' cd1.city AS 'Primary Address'
```

However, some of the fields are empty in the records, for example if there is no secondary address - so how can I make it so the secondary address doesn't output ', '? The fields are empty strings, not NULL values.

Thanks again!

EDIT: I've got this working using:

```
STUFF(COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(C1.[AddressLine1], ''), '') + 
  COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(C1.[AddressLine2], ''), '') + 
  COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(C1.[City], ''), '') + 
  COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(C1.[State], ''), '') + 
  COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(C1.[Country], ''), '') + 
  COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(C1.[ZipCode], ''), ''),1, 1, '') AS 'Primary Address'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;with cd as(
select *, rn = dense_rank(partition by bioid order by addressline, city)
from ContactDetails cd
)
select c.bioid, c.firstname, c.lastname, cd1.AddressLine, cd1.City, cd2.AddressLine, cd2.City, cd3.AddressLine, cd3.City
from Contact c 
left join cd cd1 on c.bioid = cd1.bioid and cd1.rn = 1
left join cd cd2 on c.bioid = cd2.bioid and cd2.rn = 2
left join cd cd3 on c.bioid = cd3.bioid and cd3.rn = 3
```

Comment: This will only work if he assumes that there will only be 3 addresses. If there are more than that, then he will miss data.

Comment: @JustinPihony the OP asked for only 2 addresses and I'm giving him three and a means to add more. :)

Comment: Yes, the OP said in the example data there are 2, but that was not necessarily the requirements

Comment: @JustinPihony don't think about zebras

Comment: In this case, why not especially if the cleaner approach is better and not that much more work? But, your way works if they do know a max and want each in a separate column. We can let the OP choose what works best for themselves :)

Comment: @JustinPihony you can always add `dense_rank(partition by bioid order by city, addressline)` which I'm going to to do in my script

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Thank you for providing the example, I was easily able to integrate it into a much more complex 500 line stored procedure than the example I provided, except I kept the 'over(partition by...', what is the difference for dense_rank?

Comment: @tsdexter dense_rank allows you to enumerate duplicates without losing steps; for example, if you're trying to enumerate a,a,b,b,c,c with `dense_rank` you will end up with 1,1,2,2,3,3, but if you try to enumerate this with just `rank`, you will end up with 1,1,3,3,5,5, which won't allow us to access second row with 2 and third with 3

Answer (score 4):

You could try a [PIVOT TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) or a [RECURSIVE CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx). The Pivot table would work if you know how many addresses the user will have (however, if you know that you could probably hard-code it too :)), the CTE will work for an unknown number of addresses, however, it would not create multiple columns, but instead a comma separated list.

Either way you go, you will probably need to utilize [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to create the uniqueness order.

Here is what should be a working example of the Recursive CTE:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bioid ORDER BY contactid) AS rownum
INTO #TableToRecurse
FROMContactDetails

;WITH FinalOutput AS
(
--Anchor row of recursion
SELECT bioid, firstname, lastname, addressline, city, rownum
FROM #TableToRecurse 
WHERE rownum = 1
UNION ALL 
--Recursion piece
SELECT tr.bioid, tr.firstname, tr.lastname, 
    FinalOutput.addressline + ', ' + tr.addressline, FinalOutput.city + ', ' + tr.city, tr.rownum
FROM #TableToRecurse AS tr
    JOIN FinalOutput
        ON  FinalOutput.bioid = tr.bioid AND FinalOutput.rownum = tr.rownum +1
)
--Final output only showing the last row (Max)
--Which should have everything concatenated together
SELECT FinalOutput.bioid, FinalOutput.firstname, FinalOutput.lastname, 
    FinalOutput.addressline, FinalOutput.city
FROM FinalOutput 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(rownum) AS MaxRowNum, bioid
        FROM FinalOutput
        GROUP BY bioid
    ) AS MaxForEach
        ON FinalOutput.bioid = MaxForEach.bioid 
            AND FinalOutput.rownum = MaxForEach.MaxRowNum
```

Comment: `PIVOT` will work but not obvious what to `PIVOT` on. Can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this.

Comment: Yah, I was thinking it but forgot to put that down. Thanks, it has been updated.

Comment: Any examples looking forward?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tr.rownum + 1` in the recursion select?

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I really appreciate it! I ended up using the example below because I know there are only 2 records/bioID and he had an example up quicker that I was able to integrate into a large 500 line stored procedure quite easily.

Comment: You can use a CASE, CASE WHEN column is null and column2 is null THEN '' WHEN column is null THEN column2 WHEN column2 is null THEN column ELSE column + ', ' + column2. Also, for future reference, technically this is a separate question :-p But, then that is coming from somebody who is striving for more points :D

Comment: Thanks, I up'ed your answer even though I didn't use it because I appreciate the help and it did have valuable info. The values are not NULL they are empty strings, so I used STUFF, COALESCE and NULLIF - see question for example.

Comment: Thanks. Do keep in mind that there is some overhead in processing when you use all of those functions. But, I wouldnt worry about it if you dont need to :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
    FROM   Table_1 t 

    SELECT *
FROM   Table_1 t 

SELECT af.bioid,
       af.fname,
       af.lastname,
       address1,
       city1,
       address2,
       tbl2,
       rrr
FROM   (
           SELECT tbl1.bioid,
                  tbl1.fname,
                  tbl1.lastname,
                  tbl1.addressline1 AS address1,
                  tbl1.city AS city1,
                  tbl2.addressline1 AS address2,
                  tbl2.city AS tbl2,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl1.bioid ORDER BY tbl1.bioid) AS 
                  rrr
           FROM   Table_1 tbl1,
                  Table_1 tbl2
           WHERE  tbl1.bioid = tbl2.bioid
                    AND tbl1.addressline1+tbl1.city <> tbl2.addressline1+tbl2.city
       ) af
WHERE  af.rrr = 1
```

[image]

Comment: What if you have identical addresses in different cities? Your query won't event return that person. What if that person doesn't have contact details?

Comment: @DenisValeev I gave him a way of doing this. if it is better or best - Im sure there can be a better solution ( theres always better solution)   - but he can get the idea and continue from here.

Comment: The OP said about two tables, one being ContactDetails and the other is Bio; as far as I can see you only have one

Comment: I agree that it's always better to provide half-answers.